# Can't deploy a contract to Rinkby test net with myetherwallet contract deploy

Tags: contract-deployment, myetherwallet, rinkeby

I have a problem with deploying contract on myetherwallet. It keeps showing this no mmatter what I do:

[image]

Any idea what is wrong or what I need to do? 
I tried updating syncing my node last night but some reason it was super slow and didn't even finish half.

I just want a way to easily deploy my test contracts to test net. It seems to me I am just doing something wrong here, because as a test I took a contract directly from ethereums website (the ballot one) and tried to upload it and it wont work.

EDIT: I am deploying from taking the bytecode from remix, and pasting it in metamask

Comment: I got it to work using Remix and deploying. The main issue was my contract was very high in gas (4.4 million), and some reason it was not working for a long time. Then when I increased gwei to 120 and made the gas limit the absolute max, around 4.7 million, it worked. Not sure if the issue was it was always short on gas by a bit, or if i needed to increase gwei a lot to get into a block that i was filling up almost by myself. However I still don't know how to deploy with metamask so if anyone can fill in thats great!

Comment: Apparently, online MyEtherWallet does not support contract deployment:   https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/49dj1n/how_to_upload_a_contract_with_myetherwalletcom/

Comment: You can use remix+Metamask to deploy your contract. In remix set environment to: injected web3. Then you can deploy it dirrectly from remix. In metamask state where the contract is supposed to send.

Comment: Is the recipient address valid?